# Android FacebookSDK 4.6.0 share bitmap issue

Tags: java, android, facebook, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to share a bitmap from my Android project using [this example](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android) from Facebook, but

when I implement example at my project - nothing happens, no warning, no errors. Here is My code:

```
    shareButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder()
                    .setBitmap(image)
                    .build();
            SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
                    .addPhoto(photo)
                    .build();


            ShareDialog shareDialog = new ShareDialog(MainActivity.this);

            shareDialog.show(content);



        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to register a callback to see what actually is happening.

```
    public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
        CallbackManager callbackManager;
        ShareDialog shareDialog;
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
            callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
            shareDialog = new ShareDialog(this);
            shareDialog.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>() { 
    // onSuccess method
    // onError method
    // onCancel method
 });
        }
```

Then call the SDK's callbackManager in your onActivityResult to handle the response:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```